# Can user edit android resource files? Access string from all Classes

Tags: java, android, resources, edit

I am new in android programming (Java).
I got two questions :

1. Can a simple user change android resource files(e.g. strings , colors, styles)? I mean just by editing, NOT hacking
2. I have a string (e.g. base URL of host) and I want to have access from all classes. How should I do it?

tnx anyone can help!

Comment: "Can a simple user change android resource files(e.g. strings , colors, styles)?" -- no.

Comment: (2) create a `public static final String BASE_URL = "https://...";` in one class of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to edit resources files

For your second question you can create a seperate class to atore constant values and declare variable as
" public static final yourdatatype=value"

As its a static value you can directly call this with your class name.variable name

Answer (score 0):

The resources files are immutable. Although, this isn't saying that you cannot change this properties "programmatically".

In your Java codes, you can change the colors and text of your views, for example, but not the resources.

For static data visible to all classes in your domain, maybe you should create a class with a public static field, like:

```java
public class GlobalURL {
   public static final String URL_FOO_1 = "example.com";
}
```

With this, you can call this field in any other class in your domain.

```java
String url = GlobalURL.URL_FOO_1;
```